# Dynamically display rows in listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a list box that displays information off of a column of a dataset.  I would like the number of rows displayed to be all the rows that are in the dataset (the number of datasets in the rows vary).  I'm figuring it has something to do with

ListBox.Rows = Dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

But it seems to just always default to 4 even when it is only 2.

This is what I have in my aspx.cs file.

```
                pirateBox.DataTextField = Pirateship.Tables[0].Columns["displayName"].ToString();
                pirateBox.DataValueField = pirateship.Tables[0].Columns["PKID"].ToString();
                pirateBox.DataSource = pirateship.Tables[0];
                pirateBox.DataBind();
                pirateBox.Rows = pirateship.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

I've been trying a few things and this is what I have so far in .aspx

```
<asp:ListBox ID="pirateBox" runat="server" Rows="1"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting some more code ? If your datasource has X rows and you bind it to your ListBox without doing anything more, it should be the same...

Comment: @Bartdude The Rows property *Gets or sets the number of rows displayed in the ListBox control.* I believe this affects the size of the box not the values

Comment: Is it just increasing to 4 for default? or do larger numbers work if that's what you're passing in via dataset.tables[0].rows.count? Sorry, just a little unclear if the issue is a locked default or a minimum row requirement of 4.

Comment: What does the statement about defaulting to four rows mean?  That `DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 2`, but the `ListBox` will still have four rows?  What are they?  Each of the two duplicated once?

Comment: @ConradFrix : Indeed ! I misunderstood the question. My bad.

Comment: The dataset has two rows, the listbox displays the two but then has space for two more.

Comment: To also add it appears to take more rows fine.  Just awkwardly displays it when there are two or three (displays it as if there's still four of them).  Is that possibly just default behavior?  (it displays like a drop down when there is only one row.

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint at `pirateBox.DataTextField = Pirateship.Tables[0].Columns["displayName"].ToString();` then add a watch to `Pirateship.Tables[0]` and see if it is showing 4 rows in there?

Comment: Also in the properties of the listbox (in the Visual Studio gui) check the Items (Collection) property to make sure there isn't any strange spaces or returns that are already added by default

Comment: Checked the items collection property, it was empty.

Pirateshipt.Tables[0] was still showing the rows it had (currently 3)  The PirateBox.Rows also equaled 3